# Assign event and function in extension method as argument

Tags: c#, events, extension-methods

I have a list of objects and I want to assign values in a factory method. I have checked **similar questions** but they have access to a method in **existing assembly**. I want to use a custom method and also define which event should be set.

for example

```
mylist.Assign(nameofevent,assignfuntion);
```

the usage something like

```
public static void Assign(this Control[] controls,eventhandler @event,Action func)
{
  foreach (var item in controls)
  //assign function to event
    item.clicked += func;//Preferably clicked must be Specified from argument
}
```

Comment: Could you add a bit more context on what you have tried and failed. And what you are expecting to do... can't really make that out from your question. Do you want to create a method that subscribes actions to events?

Comment: @DaveyvanTilburg I don't know how to implement it. I have a list of objects. each object contains some events. I want to select an event and function and assign it. for example, assign FunctionTest to all objects on the event Clicked.

Comment: You will have to be way more specific in what is holding you back to accomplish this. Ill add an answer showing how i'd get it to work... and tell me what is wrong with it

Comment: @DaveyvanTilburg Thanks for your help, in simple words. I have a Class A. Class A Contains clicked event.Also, have function FuncTest . I want to assign funcTest to ClassA.clicked

Comment: I've added an answer with two approaches to (what I think) you mean. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to help to get to the bottom of what is wrong with Shervin Ivari's question. I'm illustration how you can achieve it. But still unsure if this is what you want?

```
public static void Main()
{
    var listeners = new List<SomeClassWithListener>
    {
        new SomeClassWithListener(),
        new SomeClassWithListener(),
        new SomeClassWithListener()
    };

    var theEvent = new SomeClassWithEvent();

    MatchEmUp(listeners, theEvent);

    theEvent.RaiseEvent();
}

public static void MatchEmUp(IEnumerable<SomeClassWithListener> listeners, SomeClassWithEvent theEvent)
{
    foreach(SomeClassWithListener listener in listeners)
        theEvent.ItsAlive += listener.ThenIllSlayIt;
}

public class SomeClassWithListener
{
    public void ThenIllSlayIt(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Chaaaaaarge!");
    }
}

public class SomeClassWithEvent
{
    public EventHandler ItsAlive;

    public void RaiseEvent()
    {
        ItsAlive.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/4Y13cf

Or by using delegates, EventHandler is also a delegate:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var listener1 = new SomeClassWithListener();
    var listener2 = new SomeClassWithListener();
    var listener3 = new SomeClassWithListener();

    var listeners = new List<EventHandler>
    {
        listener1.ThenIllSlayIt,
        listener2.ThenIllSlayIt,
        listener3.ThenIllSlayIt
    };

    var theEvent = new SomeClassWithEvent();

    MatchEmUp(listeners, theEvent);

    theEvent.RaiseEvent();
}

public static void MatchEmUp(IEnumerable<EventHandler> listeners, SomeClassWithEvent theEvent)
{
    foreach(EventHandler listener in listeners)
        theEvent.ItsAlive += listener;
}

public class SomeClassWithListener
{
    public void ThenIllSlayIt(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Chaaaaaarge!");
    }
}

public class SomeClassWithEvent
{
    public EventHandler ItsAlive;

    public void RaiseEvent()
    {
        ItsAlive.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/k16lsy